# remove empty space in static block in magento site

Tags: css, static-block

in home page, you can see "special categories " with 6 red images.

below those images some empty space is displaying.

I want to delete those empty space.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS files locate the element `.wrapper-category .home_cat` and remove the `margin-bottom` or reset it to 0